# How can I dynamically set the focus on a lightning:input?

Tags: javascript, search, lightninginput

So I want to be able to set the focus on a lighting:input searchbar as soon as a tab is clicked, but I can't figure out how to target it. In javascript I could just do document.getElementById("someId").focus(); but lightning:input components don't have an id parameter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the focus you will need to access the component using it's id -

> You can retrieve a component using its local ID in your JavaScript
>   code. Create a local ID by using the aura:id attribute. For example:

`<lightning:button aura:id="button1" label="button1"/>`

> Find the button component by calling cmp.find("button1") in your
>   client-side controller, where cmp is a reference to the component
>   containing the button.

**Note**: This example uses a button but you can do it on input field as well and you need to do that in init which is page initiation.

Source - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_ids.htm

Comment: Please make sure you include the essentials of the links you posted, just in case they no longer become available. Thanks

Comment: @Bend'Straw did this solve your problem? I was not able to focus on `ligthning:input`, how did you solve it? I'm getting this error message `Cannot read property 'focus' of null`